# Keyword 'categorical_features' deprecated

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I was learning from an online course on Udemy. In one of the tutorials, I required to use this code and it says the keyword 'categorical_features' is deprecated. Here is the code:

```
# Multiple Linear Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

This is a multiple linear regression. The categorical data part is where things get confusing.
If someone came across this problem before or knows a solution to this please help.

this is the warning:

```
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:415: FutureWarning: The handling of integer data will change in version 0.22. Currently, the categories are determined based on the range [0, max(values)], while in the future they will be determined based on the unique values.
If you want the future behaviour and silence this warning, you can specify "categories='auto'".
In case you used a LabelEncoder before this OneHotEncoder to convert the categories to integers, then you can now use the OneHotEncoder directly.
  warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
C:\Users\admin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:451: DeprecationWarning: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. You can use the ColumnTransformer instead.
  "use the ColumnTransformer instead.", DeprecationWarning)
```

Comment: Solution to what exactly? Do you get an error, or just a warning? Please post the exact trace

Comment: Does [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/41113/deprecationwarning-the-categorical-features-keyword-is-deprecated-in-version) answer your question?

Comment: @desertnaut I have edited my question to show the error

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I will try your solution